# GoRouter: Refresh on page looses Back Button

Tags: flutter, gorouter

I have a home screen and a detail page. When I navigate to the detail page, Flutter automatically adds a back button in the AppBar that when clicked, goes back to the previous page.

Now using GoRouter, the `UrlPathStrategy.path` allows that my detail page is at `/detail` and when refreshing the page, it opens the detail page directly. This is all good, however, the problem is, there is no back button after refreshing at `/detail`.

Is there a concept, such that GoRouter can infer the Navigation stack based on the route and thus when opening the `/detail` page, show a back button that leads to `/` (home page)?

My current routes look something like this:

```
routes: [
  GoRoute(
    name: "detail",
    path: "/detail",
    builder: (context, state) => DetailPage(),
  ),
  GoRoute(
    name: "home",
    path: "/",
    builder: (context, state) => HomePage(),
  ),
],
```

Answer (score 4):

Probably just put detail route inside home route?

```
routes: [
  GoRoute(
    name: "home",
    path: "/",
    builder: (context, state) => HomePage(),
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        name: "detail",
        path: "/detail",
        builder: (context, state) => DetailPage(),
      ),
    ],
  ),
],
```

Comment: unfortunatly this is not the solution because I can go to the detail page from other pages other than the home page and thus I can't have the details page at `/home/detail`

Comment: you can go from anywhere to detail, but once in detail and user click back, it will be back to home. That one of amazing feature from go router that I like

Comment: Yes thats exactly my problem. Imagine I have a home page and a list page. From both pages I can go to detail page. When I put the detail page as a child route of home, the back button will always go to home. But when I go to detail from the list page, I want to go back to list page and not home page

Comment: then you can keep router like above, but when you're in list page you navigate with context.push, it will respect the current route, but when you go from deeplink or home, you can use context.go

Comment: I am in the same situation. I feel like @Faruk solution is not ideal, since it won't have a "native feeling" in web. I'd go to a details screen and I wouldn't see the URL being updated. One thing should be the "stack of pages" and another the "route hierarchy"

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on the page that you know you can just use the go_router `pushReplacement` instead of the `refresh`

the following is from the `router.dart`

```dart
  /// Replaces the top-most page of the page stack with the given URL location
  /// w/ optional query parameters, e.g. `/family/f2/person/p1?color=blue`.
  ///
  /// See also:
  /// * [go] which navigates to the location.
  /// * [push] which pushes the location onto the page stack.
  void pushReplacement(String location, {Object? extra}) {
    routeInformationParser
        .parseRouteInformationWithDependencies(
      RouteInformation(location: location, state: extra),
      // TODO(chunhtai): avoid accessing the context directly through global key.
      // https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99112
      _routerDelegate.navigatorKey.currentContext!,
    )
        .then<void>((RouteMatchList matchList) {
      routerDelegate.pushReplacement(matchList);
    });
  }
```

It works just great :)

Answer (score 0):

I think Frank has the proper answer.

Probably just put detail route inside home route?

```
routes: [
  GoRoute(
    name: "home",
    path: "/",
    builder: (context, state) => HomePage(),
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        name: "detail",
        path: "/detail",
        builder: (context, state) => DetailPage(),
      ),
    ],
  ),
],
```

In addition to this, for routes that need to be reached by multiple pages, you could define a new router under that parent route. In this case, DetailPage() can be accessed by context.go() from both home and check-detail. The back button would work as intended.

Note: the name of the route has to be different because it serves as an id of the route.

```
routes: [
  GoRoute(
    name: "home",
    path: "/",
    builder: (context, state) => HomePage(),
    routes: <RouteBase>[
      GoRoute(
        name: "detail",
        path: "detail",
        builder: (context, state) => DetailPage(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        name: "check-detail",
        path: "check-detail",
        builder: (context, state) => CheckDetailPage(),
        routes: <RouteBase>[
          GoRoute(
            name: "check-detail-detail",
            path: "check-detail-detail",
            builder: (context, state) => DetailPage(),
          ),
        ],
       ),
    ],
  ),
],
```